# Find and replace any or both patterns in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have list of urls. I need to strip off the protocol from it.
Some may have only http:// in it some may have www in it or some both.

I have written the code for it as:

```
my @list = qw'http://de.yahoo.com http://mail.example.org http://www.aol.com';
foreach(@list)
{
  my $string = $_;
  $string =~ s/http:\/\///;
  $string =~ s/www.//;
  print $string,"\n";
}
```

It works fine but is there a better way to write it in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
my @list = qw(http://de.yahoo.com http://mail.example.org http://www.aol.com);
foreach(@list)
{
  my $string = $_;
  $string =~ s/^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?//;
  print $string,"\n";
}
```

For future reference, http://www.regextester.com/ is your friend :)

** Edit ** Modified to use ikegami's suggestion of (?:...) as it should be more efficient when the values captured are not needed.

Comment: Thanks! I really need to work on regular expressions, should have got this one on my own.

Comment: It's really worthwhile learning to use them, not least because they're supported by many editors which is handy for code refactoring and the like!

Comment: That's not equivalent. That doesn't remove the `www.` in `http://foo.com/www.html` like the original. That's probably a good, thing, though.

Comment: @ikegami Apologies, I misread your comment. It works as epxected using the tester I linked to.

Comment: @ikegami: It would remove www. if theres no http://. ? does mean 0 or 1 occurences.

Comment: @Maxwell, oops, Comment retracted (deleted).

Comment: Using captures (`(...)`) only to discard the captured text is slow! You want `(?:...)`.

Comment: @ikegami I doubt the overhead will kill him, but that's a valid point.  Have updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want:

```
s!^(http://)?(www\.)?!!;
```

A few points:

1. use `s!a!b!` instead of `s/a/b/`, this save the `\/\/` escape.
2. use `^`, this ensure `http://` is at the start of string

As a single line:

```
print join("\n", map {s!^(http://)?(www\.)?!!;} @list);
```

Comment: Using captures (`(...)`) only to discard the captured text is slow! You want `(?:...)`.

Comment: @ikegami, It is fewer character to type :)

Comment: Perl6 uses `[]` for captures (Perl5's `()`) and `()` for grouping (Perl5's `(?:)`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
s{http://(.*)www.|www.(.*)http://|http://|www.}{$1$2}g;
```

But you probably meant to do:

```
s{^http://}[};
s{^www\.}[};
```

which can be combined into:

```
s{^(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?}{};

http://www.foo.bar/www.html?http://xxx  =>  foo.bar/www.html?http://xxx
http://foo.bar/www.html                 =>  foo.bar/www.html?http://xxx
www.foo.bar/www.html                    =>  foo.bar/www.html?http://xxx
foo.bar/www.html                        =>  foo.bar/www.html?http://xxx
```